# Did the 2019 discovery of O(N log(N)) multiplication have a practical outcome?

Tags: software, high-performance-computing, mathematical-modeling, history, algorithms

Some time ago I've read this news article, [Mathematicians Discover the Perfect Way to Multiply](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-discover-the-perfect-way-to-multiply-20190411/), reporting a discovery published in 2019, where  Harvey and Hoeven[1] found a algorithm able to execute multiplication in $N \log N$ steps. Compare with the $N^2$ we are used to while doing multiplication by hand.

That amused me, because I had no idea in Mathematics there was still open problems in basic arithmetic, something I took for granted, long ago settled knowledge, since childhood.

Now I wonder, did this discovery help, or could help, materials modeling? Did a code developed somewhere for this purpose made use of it. A downside of the new algorithm is a set up phase where you need to put the numbers in a suitable form, so this initial effort is paid only for large numbers. My impression is that in matter modeling our algorithms are more about multiplying lots of small numbers fast, instead of some big numbers, so I guess the answer is probably no. But I'm not sure.

If not, can someone explain in detail the impact of *any* of the multiplication algorithms scaling better than $N^2$, for some practical application?

[1] David Harvey, Joris van der Hoeven. Integer multiplication in time O(n log n). 2019. [⟨hal-02070778⟩](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778)

Comment: +1. It's for integer multiplication, not floating-point multiplication, so applications to Matter Modeling are limited, and there hasn't been much time since 2019, so it hasn't made its way into people's codes. But it's an interesting result indeed.

Comment: You can eliminate floating-point math by scaling every value to an integer first. However, even extremely precise calculations won't need so many digits to represent the resulting integers that the asymptotically faster algorithms would be faster than the practical O(n^2) algorithms.(See https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2016/3/16/how-many-decimals-of-pi-do-we-really-need/, for example.)

Comment: @NikeDattani, floating-point multiplication is just integer multiplication with a scaling factor.

Comment: I think it would be more useful if the algorithm could be extended to matrix multiplications. Multiplications of extremely large numbers or numbers with a large number of digits might not very common but large matrix multiplication is very often used in quantum chemistry programs.

Comment: @Mark - unfortunately it is not! Multiplication in the _rational_ field, ℚ, is as you describe.  But - _floating-point_ multiplication has to deal with limited precision ... (just quibbling ...)

Comment: @PaulieBao Matrix multiplication costs at least $N^2$ because you have to be able to read in the data, and there's $N^2$ data. So you cannot do matrix multiplication in O(N log N) steps. Maybe for special matrices that only have N*logN unique entries, it could be possible, but that would be a highly specialized algorithm for only a small subset of all matrices.

Comment: I can't tell how useful the question is but I'm glad I stumbled on it. It was nice to have learned about the discovery of a multiplication algorithm in time O(n log n). I previously read the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm, a lower bound of O(n log n) has only been conjectured.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

## What are the state-of-the-art algorithms for long-integer multiplication?

First let me address the point you raised about the schoolbook algorithm having $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ scaling, by saying that this was not the state-of-the-art algorithm used in most matter modeling software. Below I give a brief overview:

**(1960) Karatsuba multiplication. $\mathcal{O}(n^{1.58})$:** Faster than naive multiplication after $n$ gets ~$10^{96}$.
**(1963-2005) Toom-Cook-Knuth. $\mathcal{O}(n\cdot 2^{\sqrt{2\log n}}\log n)$:** Generalization of Karatsuba.
**(1971) Schönhage-Strassen. $\mathcal{O}(n\log n\log\log n)$:** Outperforms TCK after ~$10^{10000}$.
**(2007) **Fürer.**  $\mathcal{O}(n\log n\cdot 2^{\mathcal{O}(\log^*n)})$:** Outperforms SS after ~$10^{10^{18}}$.
**(2015) **Harvey *et al*.**  $\mathcal{O}(n\log n\cdot 2^{3\log^*n})$:** Similar to Fürer's algorithm.
**(2015) **Harvey *et al*.**  $\mathcal{O}(n\log n\cdot 2^{2\log^*n})$:** Relies on conjectures not yet proven.
**(2016) Covanov-Thomé.  $\mathcal{O}(n\log n\cdot 2^{2\log^*n})$:** Relies on (different) conjectures not yet proven.
**(2018) Harvey & van der Hoeven.  $\mathcal{O}(n\log n\cdot 2^{2\log^*n})$:** Finally proven without conjectures.
**(2019) Harvey & van der Hoeven.  $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$:** The algorithm mentioned in the paper you cited.

---

## Which of these algorithms have practical consequences?

**Schönhage-Strassen**: [GNU multi-precision library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) uses it for #s with 33,000 to 150,000 digits.
**Toom-Cook**: is used for intermediate-sized numbers, basically until Schönhage-Strassen is used.
**Karatsuba**: is a specific case of Toom-Cook: not likely used for numbers smaller than $10^{96}$.

---

## So what are the consequences of the 2019 algorithm?

Likely nothing for the calculations we typically do. Schönhage and Strassen predicted very long ago that $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ would be the most efficient possible algorithm from a computational complexity point of view, and in 2019 the algorithm that achieves this predicted "lower bound" was found by Harvey and van der Hoeven. It is probably not implemented in any library, just as the 2018, 2016, 2015, and 2007 algorithms are also not implemented anywhere as far as I know. They are all beautiful mathematics papers which give theoretical scalings, but likely have no practical consequences.

Do you ever multiply together integers with 96 digits? Typically in double-precision floating point arithmetic we multiply numbers with no more than 18 digits, and in quadruple-precision arithmetic (which is indeed used in matter modeling for things like numerical derivatives in variational energy calculations, but quite rarely) numbers have up to 36 digits, but it is unlikely that anyone in matter modeling is frequently multiplying numbers with 96 digits, so even the Karatsuba algorithm is in practice worse than the schoolbook $n^2$ algorithm, due to Karatsuba involving extra shifts and additions as overhead. The Toom-Cook algorithms (such as Karatsuba) are useful in number theory, and in fact *we use them every day when we do e-banking or when we use GitHub involving RSA keys*, since RSA numbers are hundreds or thousands of digits long. The Schönhage-Strassen is used mainly in number theory for things like calculating record numbers of digits in $\pi$, and for practical applications such as multiplying polynomials with huge coefficients.

**Conclusion:** The 2019 algorithm for integer multiplication does not affect real-world applications.

Comment: Nice summary.  A good reminder that $\mathcal{O}$ notation can hide large constant coefficients, making theoretical algorithms impractical for most common use cases.

Comment: Software use of an extended-precision multiply algorithm works in chunks of whatever the hardware provides, not in terms of bits directly (and definitely not decimal digits; nobody uses decimal digits as an extended-precision format.  Possibly decimal-float for some rare cases.)  Double-double floating point (wide mantissa, same exponent) only takes a handful of double-precision math operations.  The relevant width is 2 doubles, not 36 decimal digits.  (and [IEEE FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is a binary format, not decimal)

Comment: CPU hardware could internally use tricks, but as you say there aren't enough bits in one `double` so the mantissa multipliers are usually a [Dadda tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370287/how-modern-x86-processors-actually-compute-multiplications) for the 53x53-bit => 53-bits correctly rounded mantissa.  Same for the 64x64 =>128-bit integer multiply ALU.

Comment: @PeterCordes The correct numbers are: $n=2^{320} \approx 10^{96}$ for Karatsuba overtaking schoolbook algorithm, 1728-7808 64-bit words (about 30,000-150,000 digits) for the GNU implementation of Schönhage-Strassen, and $n=2^{2^{64}} \approx 10^{10^{18}}$ for Fürer's algorithm overtaking Schönhage-Strassen.

Comment: In other words, it's a [galactic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_algorithm).

Comment: @PeterCordes since this has become such a big "Hot Network Question" with about 70 upvotes already, why don't you add an answer that contains some of that knowledge that you wrote in your comments? Even if it has nothing to do with materials modeling or doesn't answer the question directly, it's completely fine. I think it would be very well received to add some of those details about how multiplication works at the "low-level". Many of us are interested in that, and on this site we've talked about materials software in **assembler**. We are a new site, so it would help shape our future.

Comment: @J.G. Same with you, if you're able to perhaps write an answer about galactic algorithms such as the Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm for matrix multiplication (which is actually quite related to the question!).

Comment: @NikeDattani Sure. I've posted a hopefully useful answer.

Comment: Please note that the `N` in this notation refers to the _size_ of the input, not to the magnitude of numbers. For algorithms on numbers, `N` is generally the number of digits. If you want `n` to be the number you should talk about `log(n)` to reflect that.

Comment: @Cubic hasn't my whole answer treared n to be the number of digits?

Comment: @NikeDattani No, it certainly doesn't take 10^{10000} digits for Schönhage-Strassen to be efficient. You'd otherwise observe that there is no practical use for the algorithm, which is far from the truth. Similar for Karatsuba etc.

Comment: @PeterCordes - w.r.t. "nobody uses decimal digits as an extended-precision format" - is that true?  I know there used to be implementations of multi precision integer arithmetic that used the largest power of 10 that would fit in a word as the base - e.g., 10^9 for 32-bit machines.  Made conversions to<->from a human-readable base 10 notation much easier and cost only a "reasonable" overhead for some definition of reasonable that might depend on your use case.  Is that not done anymore?  (Although strictly speaking those aren't decimal digits, just power-of-ten digits...)

Comment: @davidbak: That was a slight overstatement, BCD did used to be common in 8-bit machines.  A large power of 10 as a base is sane when you need frequent conversion to/from a decimal string, or multiply/divide by powers of 10. But then a 36-digit number is 4 chunks of 9, not 36 chunks of 1; I was excluding stuff like that. (use-case: frequent mul/div by powers of 10, or conversion. eg [printing the first 1000 decimal digits of `Fib(10^9)`](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135618/30206) where it's handy to have right shift by 1 limb be division by a power of 10. PowerPC even has hardware decimal-FP

Comment: @davidbak: See also this code-review answer about an implementation based on single decimal digits.  [BigInt class in C++](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237764).  It's not rare for beginners to come up with that as an idea, but non-toy libraries use at least 10^9 "limbs" (except BCD).  Or more commonly binary extended precision using all 32 bits per 32-bit integer, or sometimes only 2^30 to leave room for software handling of carry in/out, or to allow deferred carry normalization, making SIMD efficiently possible. [Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8866973)

Comment: @PeterCordes is it possible for you to combine your knowledge that's in the 4 big comments, into some type of answer? I've put a 200 point bounty on it and I'm especially interested in low-level optimizations, even if they are not so directly related to integer multiplication only!

Comment: Ok, I'll since you're specifically interested in that I'll see what I can do.  I didn't earlier because I don't know about materials modeling and this answer already answered the direct question pretty well.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes! Unfortunately I can't award the bounty to myself, so I'd be delighted to see more answers :)

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes do you still want to answer? The bounty ends tomorrow.

Comment: @CodyAldaz: Thanks for the reminder; I still might write something up.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes I can't give the bounty to my own answer. J.G's answer already earned 240 rep because it was an HNQ with 6k views, so it seems unfair to give the 200 there. Tyberius specifically told me NOT to give him the bounty, because he wants it to go to a user with smaller rep. So basically, there's no one to give the bounty to if you don't answer! haha

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your insight. I think once you write your answer it will be a great contribution to the site, and I am also curious to learn from you!

Comment: @NikeDattani: I posted something; I hope it lives up to the high expectations everyone seems to have!  I might make some more edits to tidy it up, but I did get it in under the bounty deadline :P

Comment: @etienne_ip: ping, I did eventually post an answer.

Comment: Quoting from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70646726/1048186) to another question: "David Harvey, one of the authors states: 'The new algorithm is not really practical in its current form, because the proof given in our paper only works for ludicrously large numbers. Even if each digit was written on a hydrogen atom, there would not be nearly enough room available in the observable universe to write them down.'" [This answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1362/7906) to this question elaborates. But I think you (the author of this question) already know about that.

Answer (score 35):

This $O(n\ln n)$ integer multiplication algorithm is a [galactic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_algorithm), meaning that it won't be used despite being "of lower complexity" because it only becomes more efficient than existing algorithms for problems vastly larger than any relevant to us in practice. The problem is big-$O$ notation only tells us how the algorithm behaves for *sufficiently large* $n$, whereas values of $n$ that will come up in practice will see a much worse behaviour. Section 5 of [their paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document) explains:

> In this section we present the main integer multiplication algorithm. We actually give a family of algorithms, parameterised by a dimension parameter $d\geqslant2$. Let $n_0 := 2^{d^{12}}\geqslant 2^{4096}$, and suppose that we wish to multiply integers with $n$ bits. For $n < n_0$, we may use any convenient base-case multiplication algorithm, such as the classical $O(n^2)$ algorithm. For $n\geqslant n_0$ we will describe a recursive algorithm that reduces the problem to a collection of multiplication problems of size roughly $n^{1/d}$. We will show that this algorithm achieves $M(n) = O(n\log n)$, provided that $d\geqslant1729$.

In other words, it's only worth using the new algorithm to multiply numbers with at least $\geqslant2^{1729^{12}}$ bits. (For integer multiplication, the problem size $n$ is how many bits the larger integer has, not the integer itself; but even this number would have to be so large for the algorithm to be worthwhile I'll find it useful to discuss *its* number of digits, in base $10$.) This number of bits has more than $2\times 10^{38}$ digits in base $10$. A computer using every subatomic particle in the observable universe to store one bit of data can only store a number of bits of data whose number of digits is well under $100$. So there's no chance anyone would ever have a machine capable of such multiplication regardless of algorithm. The paper notes that smaller problems should just be done with existing algorithms.

Why does $1729$ come up here? Because a $1729$-dimensional Fourier transform is used. I'm sure within a few years there will be a tweaked version that brings that number down, allowing smaller problems to be multiplied in $O(n\log n)$ time. But even if we only require $d=2$ so $n_0=2^{2^{12}}$, that's still a number with $1234$ digits in base $10$, far more than the aforementioned $100$. For what it's worth, the paper sketches a route to using $d=8$, in which case $n_0$ would have over $2\times10^{10}$ digits.

As my link to Wikipedia notes, other kinds of multiplication have also encountered galactic algorithms, such as [gradual improvements](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/mathematicians) to the [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Ramanujan was right, 1729 is a very interesting number.

Comment: So even the minimum number of (base 10) digits where this algorithm starts to win (maybe: depends on the constants) can barely be represented in an IEEE float (and even then not exactly) - you need a double? (Range for IEEE single precision float: ±1.18×10<sup>−38</sup> to ±3.4×10<sup>38</sup>)

Comment: @JamesK - I have not corresponded with the authors but 1729 is pulled out of thin air (subject to a constraint) - a quote from the paper: "In Section 5, we will simply take d := 1729 (any constant larger than K would do)." (page 7) So in fact I wouldn't be surprised if they chose 1729 over other possibilities _precisely_ because Ramanujan thought it was interesting!

Comment: @davidbak Yes and no. With some optimizations any $d>8$ would do, but the simplest version requires $d>1728$. But since $d$ is required to be a dimension, it has to be an integer. See also Sec. 5.4, and the discussion of Eq. (1.3).

Comment: I think you got it wrong in terms of estimating what a computer can calculate. $2^{x}$ numbers requires $x$ bits. An average home computer can store numbers over $x^{1024^{4}}$, it is equal to 1 GB

Comment: @IlyaGazman What do you mean, $x^{1024^4}$? If you mean $2^{1024^4}$, that takes a terabyte. But I'm not wrong about how storage works. A computer made of the observable universe's particles could store about a googol bits, and store integers about as large as a googolplex. And a googl bits doesn't even come close to $2^{2^{12}}$ bits.

Comment: @J.G. tnx, I thought that $n$ is the number size not the bit length of the number. That indeed insane!

Answer (score 24):

To take a slight detour, we can also look at the progress of matrix multiplication algorithms. As mentioned in a few comments here, standard matrix multiplication is $O(n^{3})$ and any exact method for a general matrix is going to require $O(n^{2})$ operations just to process all the elements of initial matrices. Over the last 50 years, different methods have been developed to reduce the exponent, often denoted $\omega$. These could in principle be very useful for matter modeling, as a number of electronic structure and molecular dynamics methods rely on matrix multiplication and matrix operations which have been shown to scale the same (determinant, inversion, Gaussian elimination) or in a way expressible in terms of $\omega$ (eigenvalues).

The simplest such approach, and thus the most likely to be applied in practice, is the 1971 Strassen Algorithm, which has $O(n^{\log_2(7)})=O(n^{2.804...})$ scaling. It achieves this by recursively breaking the initial matrices into 4 blocks and storing intermediate quantities such that you can perform 7, rather than the typical 8, block multiplications.

Fairly recent studies suggest that the crossover point where it becomes more efficient than standard matrix multiplication is somewhere between $n=512$ and $n=1024$ (the method works best with widths that are powers of two due the repeated splits into 4 blocks), which are not unreasonable sizes to encounter in a large molecular electronic structure calculation. In practice, the better scaling in general is traded for greater speed for specific cases by setting a threshold size below which the recursion is stopped and replaced with standard matrix multiplication. I don't know off hand of any program that actually uses this method, but it seems like it would be simple addition and could produce tangible speedups for larger systems.

The last significant improvement was the 1990 Coopersmith-Winograd Algorithm, which scales as $O(n^{2.376...})$. The algorithm is much more complicated than the original Strassen algorithm; the proof of the scaling relates the rank of a particular trilinear form of tensor products to $\omega$. This complexity manifests in a very large prefactor, making the method much slower than the Strassen method or standard matrix multiplication. The impractically large matrices needed to reach the crossover threshold for these later approaches has led them to be referred to as galactic algorithms.

These later approaches currently have no use in matter modeling (or really any practical application), but could have significance in the long run. While the current thread of research has focused on proving a lower bound for $\omega$, this work could provide the impetus for producing more practical algorithms by proving that better scaling than the standard algorithm is possible.

Comment: @NikeDattani I have always thought this was an interesting topic and wanted the opportunity to explore it more.

Answer (score 19):

> Can someone explain in detail the impact of any of the multiplication algorithms scaling better than N<sup>2</sup>, for some practical application?

An actual application is right in front of our eyes: [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) using [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). If I click on the lock icon for the present page in my browser, then on the arrow on the right of *Connection secure*, then *More Information*, then *View Certificate*, I see that the connection uses this RSA-2048 public key:
[image: public key]
This means that at each new connection, the browser performs modular arithmetic with 2048-bit integers, that is 616-decimal digit integers.

In order to authenticate the server (or, in a previous operation, to check its certificate, which must be done at least once on the first connection), it is computed A<sup>65537</sup> mod M for the 2048-bit M in the picture, and A of the same size. Since 65537 = 2<sup>16</sup>+1, that requires 17 modular multiplications. Each can be (and often is) performed by multiplying two 2048-bit integers into a 4096-bit integer, followed by modular reduction by way of an other multiplication of 2048-bit integers.

That arithmetic is performed using *limbs* (the equivalent of decimal digits) that typically are 32-bit (sometime 64-bit, or 16-bit on low-end mobile devices). It is thus performed multiplication of integers of width N = 64 limbs. With the schoolbook algorithm, each multiplication requires N<sup>2</sup> multiplications of two limbs and additions of the result, each requiring in the order of 50 CPU clock cycles. At 1 GHz, we are talking 17×2×64×64×50×10<sup>-9</sup> s that is ≈7 ms, which is not negligible because establishing an https connection (or checking a certificate) is so common.

In order to reduce delay and power consumption, it pays to use at least the simplest of the below-O(N<sup>2</sup>) multiplication algorithms: [Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), which is O(N<sup>≈1.6</sup>). There is a threshold before that pays (especially on modern CPUs with fast multipliers), which can be down to about 10 limbs ([reference](https://www.cymatics.cc/Karatsuba-Multiplication.html)). For 64×64 limbs, Karatsuba would typically reduce computing time by a factor of nearly (4/3)<sup>2</sup> ≈ 1.7, which is better than nothing. That's part of why implementations based on [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) are faster. For low-end devices with 16-bit limbs, or when doing 4096-bit RSA, that's a factor (4/3)<sup>3</sup> ≈ 2.3, and quite worth using.

On the server side, there are more computations (about 50 times more work) and that can sometime represent a sizable fraction of the total workload, but the incentive to use Karatsuba for the bulk of the work is actually lower: the numbers manipulated are half as wide, and sometime the limbs are bigger.

---

There are other applications of [Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) and its generalization [Toom-Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) in cryptography, not limited to RSA; e.g. batch verification of ECC signatures, see Daniel J. Bernstein's [Batch binary Edwards](https://binary.cr.yp.to/bbe-20090604.pdf). In the specialized subfield of cryptanalysis, there even are uses of [Schönhage-Strassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm), e.g. [cryptanalysis of ISO 9796-2 signatures](http://www.crypto-uni.lu/jscoron/publications/iso97962joc.pdf#page=10). It's in [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) for a reason.

The recent [Harvey-Hoeven algorithm](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document) is a satisfying achievement, but is not going to be used in practical applications. I even doubt that it can ever be implemented: it seems to work for numbers in the order of 1729<sup>12</sup> bits, which is about 10<sup>22</sup> times the RAM in a [current supercomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugaku_(supercomputer)).

Comment: +10. fgrieu has arrived!

Comment: Wow this is such a great answer! It's awesome to see how these algorithms are important, even if currently inapplicable to matter modeling. It adds a lot to the discussion by means of a detailed example.

Comment: This might be a typo. "when doing 4096-bit RSA, that's a factor of (4/3)^2≈2.3". But (4/3)^2≈1.7 as mentioned earlier in your answer.

Comment: @Rashid Rafeek : typo indeed, fixed, thanks for the report.

Comment: *each requiring in the order of 50 CPU clock* - That's a big over-estimate for modern x86.  A well tuned implementation using MULX / ADOX/ADCX (https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.pdf) should get close to 1 limb x limb => 2N multiply per clock on Broadwell or later, including doing the add-with-carry dep chains.  `mul r64` throughput is at worst 4 cycles (per operation) on mainstream CPUs going back to Core 2 or Bulldozer.  So lets say maybe 5 cycles per limb-multiply as a worst case for x86-64.

Comment: Maybe 50 cycles makes sense for some very low-end things, like no HW multiplier at all?  ARM Cortex-M3 always has a multiply instruction, but [it has a silicon option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Instruction_sets) for it to be small or fast: 32x32 => 32-bit multiply is 1 cycle or 32 cycles (so that would be 16-bit limbs).  32x32 => 64-bit multiply is only present in some Cortex-M models, but if it exists it's fast-ish, like 3 to 5 cycles.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: one needs to account for the memory accesses for operand and results, and that adds a lot (and as an aside there's a pesky carry propagation from one limb to the other at each muladd, which has a cost, especially from C). Karatsuba on large operands reduces memory accesses, and that accounts for why it pays even on modern architectures, but only late (starting about RSA-1024). On CPUs without a fast multiplier, it pays sooner. I agree that 50 is quite on the high side for a competent implementation in assembly. Not all implementations are such.

Comment: 4096 bits is only 512 bytes, or 8x 64-byte cache lines.  That's pretty trivially small and will easily stay hot in L1d cache (even considering 2 inputs and a double-width result that's only 2048 bytes total).  Schoolbook multiplication doesn't need temporary storage beyond the result.   It also has linear access patterns so if data was cold in cache, there's some spatial locality benefits allowing some work to continue while waiting for the 2nd line to arrive, and should benefit well from HW prefetch for memory-level parallelism.

Comment: And yes, adc chains are hard, that's why Intel introduced new instructions (ADCX / ADOX) to allow more ILP for them when mixed with MULX.  But even without that, it's not terrible.  If your HW mul has much worse than 1 cycle throughput, you can afford to waste some instructions on carry propagation, possibly even as bad as what a C compiler would make.  The slower `mul` is, the easier it is to bottleneck on it, not front-end bandwidth.  (Assuming even modest OoO exec and pipelined multiply).

Comment: @Peter Cordes. Yes, everything fits a modern L1 cache. Yes, the memory access patterns of textbook multiplication are nice, much nicer than Karasuba, and modern x86 CPUs are good at overlapping these things. Yes my 50 is on the high side for a competent implementation, and very much so if we bring new instructions (ADCX / ADOX). Can we agree that Karatsuba pays, modestly, at RSA-2048, more so for RSA-4096, and is sometime used for this reason?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  I mostly objected to the suggestion that memory access could explain a large cost.  CPUs these days either have caches, or they're clocked so low that memory access is cheap-ish.  I think Karatsuba wins because it reduces the amount of ALU work needed, and that's the dominant factor for most BigInteger functions.

Answer (score 16):

Even the simplest better-than-schoolbook (O(n^2)) algorithms like Karatsuba are only useful in practice for large `n`.  **But what is `n`?  It's not single bits, and it's not decimal digits.**  (Posting this tangent as requested in comments.)

Software implementations of an extended-precision multiply algorithm work in integer chunks as wide as the hardware provides.  On a 64-bit CPU, that's usually 64x64 => 128-bit integer multiplication, e.g. the [x86-64 `mul` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul).  ([@fgrieu's answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/did-the-2019-discovery-of-on-logn-multiplication-have-a-practical-outcome/1409#1409) has more detail on this, including the term "limb" for such a chunk.)

That fixed-width CPU instruction runs in fixed time (regardless of the *value* on most CPUs; [division is the only instruction that's slow enough to justify variable latency in a modern pipelined CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125033/floating-point-division-vs-floating-point-multiplication/45899202#45899202), and in the most recent x86-64 CPUs even it's constant).  e.g. on modern Intel and AMD CPUs, `mul r64` or `mulx` have a throughput of 1 per cycle and a latency of 3 to 4 cycles (for the low and high halves of the output, respectively: https://www.uops.info/html-instr/MUL_R64.html).

Hardware doesn't "know" it's doing one big multiply, it's just doing each fixed-width part separately.  Hardware can easily be parallel (adding partial products) if you can throw enough transistors at the problem.  [HW multipliers in CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370287/how-modern-x86-processors-actually-compute-multiplications) use the [Dadda tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadda_multiplier) design.  This is simpler than doing 63 additions of shifted versions of the other 64-bit input (or `0` where this input has a 0 bit) using normal adders: carry propagation can be deferred.  Hardware tricks like that are AFAIK unrelated to any of the sub-N^2 algorithmic tricks.

---

Such a multiply instruction, and add-with-carry, are the building blocks for schoolbook multiplication's O(n^2) time complexity.  e.g. 128-bit multiplication (producing a 128-bit result) takes 3 multiplies on x86-64: https://godbolt.org/z/qBAbfQ.  To also produce the high half, all of those multiplies would have to be "full" 64x64=>128 instead of only 64x64 => 64 for the low x high and high x low cross products, and we'd need to do the high x high product, for a total of 4 `mul` instructions.

e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217920/32-bit-extended-multiplication-via-stack/33218993#33218993) shows 32x32 => 64-bit multiply using 16-bit x86 so each input is 2 limbs, and the output is 2+2 = 4 limbs, requiring 2*2 = 4 multiplies of 16x16 => 32 bits each.  Exactly the same pattern would apply for 64x64 => 128 on a 32-bit machine, or 128x128 => 256 on a 64-bit machine.

**Since that building block is opaque to software, and/or shuffling individual bits around would be much more expensive than it's worth, `n` is only 64 for 4096-bit integer multiply.**

To allow better instruction-level parallelism (letting [superscalar CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor) do the same work in less time) and reducing overhead of `mov` instructions, Intel introduced (in Broadwell) the ADX extension that allows two parallel dependency chains of add-with-carry.  [This whitepaper](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.pdf) shows the advantages it gives for small problems (like 512-bit x 512-bit multiplication (8 x 8 limbs)).

---

For floating-point, an FP multiplier involves an integer multiplier for the 53x53-bit => 53-bit correctly rounded mantissa (the most significant 53 bits of the full integer product) plus hardware to add the exponents, and check for / handle overflow / underflow and NaN.  See [Why does Intel's Haswell chip allow floating point multiplication to be twice as fast as addition?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452181/why-does-intels-haswell-chip-allow-floating-point-multiplication-to-be-twice-as) for some info about how FP ALUs are designed, and the barely-related question of why Intel made the design choices they did in Haswell and Skylake.

To get extra FP precision, one technique is so-called "[double-double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)": wide mantissa using two `double`s, but only the exponent from one of them.  Using that only takes a handful of double-precision math operations, like [6 to 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647409/float128-and-double-double-arithmetic) depending on which operation and whether FMA (fused multiply-add without intermediate rounding) is available.  **The relevant width is n=2 doubles, not n=36 decimal digits.** (And [IEEE FP is a binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), not decimal, although there are decimal FP formats that exist, with some CPUs even having hardware support for them, such as PowerPC.)

Note that a SIMD multiplier just replicates that for each SIMD element.  double-double can SIMD efficiently if you store separate vectors of lo / hi halves so you don't need to shuffle to line up the corresponding halves of a single number.  e.g. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573443/optimize-for-fast-multiplication-but-slow-addition-fma-and-doubledouble).

---

#### Other extended-precision number representations

You *could* store numbers as an array of bytes, each byte holding a single decimal digit.  But that's pretty terrible.  Historically, it was not uncommon to use a simplistic format like that, especially for a score counter in a game that gets printed on screen in decimal format constantly.  Or [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Packed_BCD) (2 decimal digits per 8-bit byte, each in a separate 4-bit nibble).

But this is pretty bad, especially for multiplying numbers stored in this format, because then `n` becomes large and complexity scales with N^2 (for the simple schoolbook algorithm).

@davidbak commented:

> w.r.t. "nobody uses decimal digits as an extended-precision format" - is that true? I know there used to be implementations of multi precision integer arithmetic that used the largest power of 10 that would fit in a word as the base - e.g., 10^9 for 32-bit machines. Made conversions to<->from a human-readable base 10 notation much easier and cost only a "reasonable" overhead for some definition of reasonable that might depend on your use case. Is that not done anymore? (Although strictly speaking those aren't decimal digits, just power-of-ten digits...)

Indeed, larger powers of 10 could be sane when you need frequent conversion to/from a decimal string, or multiply/divide by powers of 10. But then a 36-digit number is 4 chunks of 9, not 36 chunks of 1.  e.g. one use-case was [printing the first 1000 decimal digits of `Fib(10^9)` (x86-64 asm code-golf)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135618/30206) where it's handy to have right shift by 1 limb be division by a power of 10, and for conversion to decimal to only need to consider the current limb, converting that to 9 decimal digits without having to do extended-precision division where the remainder depends on all higher bits.

**See also [this code-review answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237764) about an implementation based on single decimal digits**.  I included some details about what CPython does, and some other links.  It's not rare for beginners to come up with that as an idea, but non-toy libraries use at least 10^9 as the base for "limbs", unless we're talking about BCD.

Or more commonly binary extended precision using all 32 bits per 32-bit integer, or sometimes only 2^30 to leave room for high-level language handling of carry in/out (like in CPython) without access to an asm carry flag.

---

Another advantage of leaving some spare bits per limb is to allow deferred carry normalization, making SIMD for addition efficiently possible. See @Mysticial's answer on [Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8866973).  Especially for extended-precision addition, leaving some slack in each limb is actually interesting if you design around that format with awareness of when to normalize as an extra step.  (@Mysticial is the author of y-cruncher and also works on Prime95; he implemented its use of FP-FMA to take advantage of the FP mantissa multipliers for bit-exact integer work.)

That answer also points out that "really large bignum" multiplications can be done as an FFT.

Normally (with standard techniques) it's very hard to take advantage of SIMD for extended-precision; within one operation, there's a serial dependency between each element: you don't know if there's carry-in to this element until you process the previous element (for addition).

For multiplication, it's usually even worse: SIMD doesn't usually have very wide multipliers, and with the result being twice as wide as the inputs it's a problem where to put them.

The amount of work done by one building block [should be measured as the "product bits" you compute per cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807341/simd-signed-with-unsigned-multiplication-for-64-bit-64-bit-to-128-bit/28811226#28811226), e.g. 64x64 => 128-bit full multiply does 64x64 = 4096 units of work.  But a 4x 32x32=>64-bit SIMD multiply (like AVX2 `vpmuludq`) does `32^2` = 1024 units of work per element, with 4 elements, for a total of 4096 units of multiply work.  And it leaves more adding of partial products not done.  So even in theory, ignoring other factors, AVX2 `vpmuludq` on a 256-bit vector is break-even with scalar.

AVX512 has 64x64 => 64-bit multiply (but still no way to get the upper-half of the full result so it's no more helpful for BigInteger than 32x32 => 64, I think).  [AVX512IFMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#IFMA) more directly exposes what the FP mantissa multipliers can do, providing separate low and high half 52x52 => 104-bit multiply.

(Other SIMD integer multiply instructions like `vpmulld` that do 32x32 => 32-bit usually decode to two separate uops for the vector-ALU ports, so they can use the same per-element multipliers as FP mantissas.  But those multipliers are only 52x52 or 24x24-bit.  Making them wider would cost significantly more for these wide SIMD ALUs, and only help the fairly rarely used SIMD-integer multiply instructions.)

Answer (score 15):

### Practical importance: compactifying explanations

It is widely believed that $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$  is the best possible result, and therefore we no longer have to say $\mathcal{O}(n\log n\cdot 2^{2\log^*n})$ every single time in every single paper in related fields, we can just say $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ every time now. Here is a related quote from Reddit:

> "The result is of extreme practical importance. Not for actually
> multiplying integers (as usual with these algorithms it's probably not
> faster than existing algorithms for integers that can be stored in the
> observable universe), but for writing papers. It has always been a
> hassle to write down the complexity of integer multiplication or
> algorithms based on integer multiplication by introducing soft-O
> notation, little-o exponents, epsilons greater than 0, or iterated
> logarithms. From now on I can just write O(n log n) in my papers and
> be done with it!"

While this might not be the answer you're looking for, about practical impact on computations, it does in fact answer the question of "What is the practical value of this algorithm?"

Comment: Rather than downvoting a brand new user, I ask you to consider editing the post to say it's practical importance is in compactifying explanations, rather than just a copy-paste answer. Otherwise I'll do it when I've finished my morning activities.

Comment: I upvoted because I nearly always approve of a sense of humor, even on the notoriously humor-impacted stack exchange sites. (In moderation, of course.)

Comment: @davidbak Thank you, I appreciate it! When I woke up someone had downvoted, until I evened it out. I also appreciate humor, but in this case the user has also technically answered the questioned correctly, in a way that I had not expected at all. The question is "what is a practical use?" and the user has very correctly given a practical use. This might be funny but it's also correct.

Comment: In at least some contexts, they'd write $M(n)$ instead.

Comment: True but then they have to explain what M(n) is, so the user Валерий Заподовников does have a point.